# How to reduce the vertical white space between ipython notebook cells?

Tags: customization, jupyter-notebook

I teach a class using ipython/jupyter notebook on a pubic computer. When the notebook is projected, the text is too small for the students to read.  I can increase the font size by pressing Ctrl+ a few times, but then not enough cells fit on the screen.

Is there any way to decrease the white space between ipython notebook cells. Is there a solution that changes just the one notebook, like this one for widening the cell width:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

I don't want to change any customization files, since the machine will be wiped when I logged out.

Comment: If you teach CS, you might be interested in https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/ (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter through here https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators)

Comment: thanks for the link, Ben. I'll check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked for, but [jupyther themes](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes) allows easily switching between whole themes, as well as changing font sizes and line heights with a simple switch at the command line, e.g.

```
jt -t grade3 -T -f roboto -fs 14 -lineh 120
```

This increases font size to 14 points and reduces line height to 120%, while (I think) keeping vertical separation among cells constant.

Of course, if the machine is wiped at logout you would need to reinstall the package at login :\

Comment: thanks! it works on my local machine, but not on the class computer because I don't have admin permissions to install any packages... :(